# Finding powers of 2 and 3 in modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> Find all the powers of $2$ and $3$ modulo $17$.

How would you solve this question and explain the steps please!

Comment: I have just been manually calculating the powers of 2 and 3 in mod 17, increasing the exponents consecutively. But the question is where do I stop, and why? It feels like there should be a purpose to the question otherwise it would just go on infinitely.

Comment: $3$ is a primitive root, so every number besides $0$ is a power of $3$ modulo $17$.  We have $2 = 3^{14} \pmod{17}$

Comment: This question seems ambiguous.  Is the question asking to compute $2^1,2^2,2^3,\dots$ and $3^1,3^2,3^3,\dots$, or is it asking you to find the residues that are powers of both $2$ and $3$ (i.e. the numbers that show up on both lists)?

Comment: The question is literally exactly as written above, no other instruction, which is why I am confused and do not know how far I have to go to answer the question.

Comment: @AmandaM where did you come across the question?  Could you ask for clarification from the source?

Answer (score 3):

If you want all the powers explicitly there's no other way but computing them. If you want some beforehand information on about how many computations you have to do you can reason along the following lines.

- You know that $2^4=16\equiv-1\bmod17$. Thus $2^8=(2^4)^2\equiv(-1)^2=1\bmod17$ and so there are just $8$ different powers of $2\bmod17$ to compute.
- $3^2=9\equiv-8=-2^3\bmod17$, so **up to a sign** the even powers of $3$ are powers of $2$ which you already have computed. In fact $3^8=(3^2)^4\equiv(-2^3)^4=(2^4)^3\equiv-1\bmod17$ because of the previous computation so that the cycle of the powers of $3\bmod 17$ has length $16$ thus including **all** non-zero classes in $\Bbb Z_{17}$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that:

$$2^m\equiv k \pmod{17} \implies 2^{m+1}\equiv 2k \pmod {17}$$

We can then list, remembering that if our $k$ is greater than $17$, we subtract $17$ from it.

$$1\equiv 1 \pmod {17}$$
$$2\equiv 2 \pmod {17}$$
$$4\equiv 4 \pmod {17}$$
$$8\equiv 8 \pmod {17}$$
$$16\equiv 16 \pmod {17}$$
$$32\equiv 15 \pmod {17}$$
(Because $16\cdot 2= 32$, but $32>17$ so we apply $32-17=15$)
$$64\equiv 13 \pmod {17}$$
(Because $15\cdot 2 = 30$, but $30>17$, so we apply $30-17=13$)

$$128\equiv 9 \pmod {17}$$
(same as above)
$$256\equiv 1 \pmod {17}$$
And now we have a cycle, so  $2^k\equiv 1,2,4,8,9,13,15,16\pmod{17}$

Now do the same for the powers of $3$. As a check, you should get $3^k\not\equiv 0 \pmod{17}$

Comment: The cycle for $3$ is a lot longer, so work in powers of $3$ instead of doing tiring amounts of arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped!

Comment: @AmandaM no problem glad it helped!

Comment: To the downvoter, care to explain why this is unsatisfactory?

Answer (score -1):

Just do it.

As $17$ is prime we know by Fermat's Little Theorem that at most there will be $17-1=16$ of them, but there might be fewer if $a^k \equiv 1\pmod{17}$ and $k\mid 16$.

$2^1 \equiv 2 \pmod {17}$

$2^2 \equiv 2*2\equiv 4 \pmod {17}$

$2^3 \equiv 2*4 \equiv 8 \pmod {17}$

$2^4 \equiv 2*8\equiv 16 \equiv -1 \pmod {17}$.  COOL!  $2^8\equiv (2^4)^2 \equiv (-1)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{17}$ so there will only be $8$ of them!

$2^5 \equiv 2*(-1) \equiv -2 \equiv 15 \pmod{17}$

$2^6 \equiv 2*(-2) \equiv -4 \equiv 13 \pmod{17}$

$2^7 \equiv 2*(-4) \equiv -8 \equiv 9 \pmod {17}$

$2^8 \equiv 2*9\equiv 18 \equiv 1 \pmod{17}$

So that's it for $2$s.

....

$3$s.

$3^1 \equiv 3\pmod{17}$

$3^2 \equiv 3*3 \equiv 9 \pmod{17}$

$3^3 \equiv 3*9 \equiv 27 \equiv 10\equiv -7 \pmod {17}$

$3^4 \equiv 3*(-7)\equiv -21\equiv -4 \equiv 13 \pmod {17}$

$3^5 \equiv 3*(-4) \equiv -12\equiv 5 \pmod{17}$.

$3^6 \equiv 3*5 \equiv 15\equiv -2 \pmod {17}$

$3^7 \equiv 3*(-2) \equiv -6 \equiv 11 \pmod {17}$.

$3^8 \equiv 3*(-6) \equiv -18 \equiv -1 \pmod {17}$

As $3^8 \equiv -1$ we can do the rest by taking negatives

$3^9 \equiv -3^1 \equiv -3 \equiv 14 \pmod{17}$.

$3^{10} \equiv -3^2 \equiv -9 \equiv 8 \pmod {17}$

$3^{11} \equiv -3^3 \equiv 7\pmod {17}$

$3^{12} \equiv -3^4 \equiv 4 \pmod {17}$

$3^{13} \equiv - 3^5 \equiv 12 \pmod {17}$

$3^{14} \equiv -3^6 \equiv 2 \pmod {17}$

$3^{15} \equiv -3^7 \equiv 6 \pmod{17}$

$3^{16} \equiv -3^8 \equiv 1 \pmod {17}$.

And that's it for the $3$s.